# export big ResultSet to excel file in streaming manner

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to export a big `ResultSet` to excel file using streaming manner to avoid too large heap consumption.

here is my testing code:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/data/export", produces = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
    public void exportData(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=demo.xlsx");
        String sql = "SELECT\n" + "    zh.jxdxdh,\n" + "    zh.zhdh,\n" + "    zh.zzh,\n" + "    zh.zhhm,\n" + "    zh.khh,\n" + "    zh.zhye,\n" + "    jg.jgmc,\n" + "    zh.kmh,\n"
                + "    bz.bzzwmc bz,\n" + "    zh.khrq,\n" + "    zh.nll,\n" + "    zh.xhrq,\n" + "    fh.jgmc    fhjgmc,\n" + "    glxzh.jgmc ssglxzh,\n" + "    TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR(zh.qx, 2)) || \n"
                + "    CASE\n" + "        WHEN SUBSTR (zh.qx, 1, 1) = 'D' \n" + "        THEN '天'\n" + "        WHEN SUBSTR (zh.qx, 1, 1) = 'M' \n" + "        THEN '月'\n"
                + "        WHEN SUBSTR (zh.qx, 1, 1) = 'Y' \n" + "        THEN '年'\n" + "    END                    qx,\n" + "    NULL                   ffrq,\n" + "    NVL (fpzt.ztms, '未分配') fpzt,\n"
                + "    NVL (fpzt.fpgx, '无关系') fpms\n" + "FROM\n" + "    khdx_jg jg\n" + "LEFT JOIN \n" + "    khdx_jg fh \n" + "ON \n" + "    fh.jgdh = jg.FHDH\n" + "LEFT JOIN \n"
                + "    khdx_jg glxzh \n" + "ON \n" + "    glxzh.JGDH = jg.glxzhdh\n" + "INNER JOIN \n" + "    jxdx_ckzh zh \n" + "ON \n" + "    jg.jgdh = zh.jgdh\n" + "INNER JOIN \n"
                + "    TABLE ( fn_getsjjg_java_qx (20201130, 215, 6) ) jgqx \n" + "ON \n" + "    jgqx.khdxdh = jg.khdxdh\n" + "LEFT JOIN \n" + "    csb_bz bz \n" + "ON \n" + "    bz.bz = zh.bz\n"
                + "LEFT JOIN \n" + "    dxgx_lxbs_ck fpzt \n" + "ON \n" + "    fpzt.jxdxdh = zh.jxdxdh\n" + "LEFT JOIN \n" + "    khdx_hy hy \n" + "ON \n" + "    zh.khdxdh = hy.khdxdh\n" + "WHERE\n"
                + "    zh.zhbs = '1'\n" + "AND NVL (fpzt.fpzt, '1') != '4'\n" + "AND zh.khrq BETWEEN 20121130 AND 20221130";
        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try (Connection conn = ds.getConnection(); Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(); ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql); SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(1000)) {
            long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("sql :" + (t2 - t1));
            SXSSFSheet sh = wb.createSheet();
            int i = 0;
            while (rs.next()) {
                SXSSFRow row = sh.createRow(i++);
                row.createCell(0).setCellValue(rs.getString(1));
                row.createCell(1).setCellValue(rs.getString(2));
                row.createCell(2).setCellValue(rs.getString(3));
                row.createCell(3).setCellValue(rs.getString(4));
                row.createCell(4).setCellValue(rs.getString(5));
                row.createCell(5).setCellValue(rs.getDouble(6));
                row.createCell(6).setCellValue(rs.getString(7));
                row.createCell(7).setCellValue(rs.getString(8));
                row.createCell(8).setCellValue(rs.getString(9));
                row.createCell(9).setCellValue(rs.getString(10));
            }
            
            wb.write(response.getOutputStream());
            long t3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("data :" + (t3 - t2));
            wb.dispose();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

the `ResultSet` is about 150k rows, 10M in excel format, 20M in text format.
but when observing with visualvm it seems it still use too much heap space:
[image]

and jstat output:

```
Timestamp        S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       MC     MU    CCSC   CCSU   YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   
           44.2 10240.0 10240.0  0.0    0.0   129024.0 64436.1   183808.0   20149.8   35416.0 33217.5 4736.0 4287.8      3    0.039   2      0.069    0.108
           45.2 10240.0 10240.0  0.0    0.0   129024.0 64436.1   183808.0   20149.8   35416.0 33217.5 4736.0 4287.8      3    0.039   2      0.069    0.108
           46.2 10240.0 10240.0  0.0    0.0   129024.0 64436.1   183808.0   20149.8   35416.0 33217.5 4736.0 4287.8      3    0.039   2      0.069    0.108
           47.2 10240.0 10240.0  0.0    0.0   129024.0 67020.7   183808.0   20149.8   35416.0 33217.5 4736.0 4287.8      3    0.039   2      0.069    0.108
           48.2 10240.0 10240.0  0.0    0.0   129024.0 110314.5  183808.0   20149.8   35416.0 33217.5 4736.0 4287.8      4    0.039   2      0.069    0.108
Timestamp        S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       MC     MU    CCSC   CCSU   YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   
           49.2 10240.0 10240.0 10210.6  0.0   171008.0 42862.7   183808.0   26249.5   50648.0 47664.6 6656.0 6102.0      4    0.071   2      0.069    0.139
           50.2 10240.0 10240.0 10210.6  0.0   171008.0 89785.6   183808.0   26249.5   50648.0 47664.6 6656.0 6102.0      4    0.071   2      0.069    0.139
           51.2 10240.0 10240.0 10210.6  0.0   171008.0 151782.9  183808.0   26249.5   50648.0 47664.6 6656.0 6102.0      4    0.071   2      0.069    0.139
           52.2 18432.0 10240.0  0.0   10225.5 191488.0 47935.1   183808.0   27857.0   54744.0 51887.3 7168.0 6606.8      5    0.090   2      0.069    0.159
           53.2 18432.0 10240.0  0.0   10225.5 191488.0 119230.3  183808.0   27857.0   54744.0 51887.3 7168.0 6606.8      5    0.090   2      0.069    0.159
Timestamp        S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       MC     MU    CCSC   CCSU   YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   
           54.2 18432.0 10240.0  0.0   10225.5 191488.0 189903.0  183808.0   27857.0   54744.0 51887.3 7168.0 6606.8      5    0.090   2      0.069    0.159
           55.2 18432.0 18432.0 10213.9  0.0   222208.0 70351.7   183808.0   27857.0   54744.0 51898.3 7168.0 6606.8      6    0.110   2      0.069    0.179
           56.2 18432.0 18432.0 10213.9  0.0   222208.0 143874.8  183808.0   27857.0   54744.0 51898.3 7168.0 6606.8      6    0.110   2      0.069    0.179
           57.2 18432.0 18432.0 10213.9  0.0   222208.0 213608.1  183808.0   27857.0   54744.0 51898.3 7168.0 6606.8      6    0.110   2      0.069    0.179
           58.2 17920.0 18432.0  0.0   10196.2 222208.0 59701.9   183808.0   27865.0   54744.0 51898.3 7168.0 6606.8      7    0.127   2      0.069    0.195
Timestamp        S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       MC     MU    CCSC   CCSU   YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   
           59.2 17920.0 18432.0  0.0   10196.2 222208.0 130425.7  183808.0   27865.0   54744.0 51898.3 7168.0 6606.8      7    0.127   2      0.069    0.195
           60.2 17920.0 18432.0  0.0   10196.2 222208.0 193431.8  183808.0   27865.0   54744.0 51898.3 7168.0 6606.8      7    0.127   2      0.069    0.195
           61.2 12288.0 17920.0 10086.2  0.0   275456.0 39591.1   183808.0   27865.0   54744.0 51898.3 7168.0 6606.8      8    0.140   2      0.069    0.209
           62.2 12288.0 17920.0 10086.2  0.0   275456.0 108308.6  183808.0   27865.0   54744.0 51898.3 7168.0 6606.8      8    0.140   2      0.069    0.209
           63.2 12288.0 17920.0 10086.2  0.0   275456.0 177272.0  183808.0   27865.0   54744.0 51898.3 7168.0 6606.8      8    0.140   2      0.069    0.209
Timestamp        S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       MC     MU    CCSC   CCSU   YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   
           64.2 12288.0 17920.0 10086.2  0.0   275456.0 249662.2  183808.0   27865.0   54744.0 51898.3 7168.0 6606.8      8    0.140   2      0.069    0.209
           65.2 17408.0 17920.0  0.0   10245.0 275456.0 40978.0   183808.0   27873.0   54744.0 51899.0 7168.0 6607.3      9    0.153   2      0.069    0.221
           66.2 17408.0 17920.0  0.0   10245.0 275456.0 107626.2  183808.0   27873.0   54744.0 51899.0 7168.0 6607.3      9    0.153   2      0.069    0.221
           67.2 17408.0 17920.0  0.0   10245.0 275456.0 173886.5  183808.0   27873.0   54744.0 51899.0 7168.0 6607.3      9    0.153   2      0.069    0.221
           68.2 17408.0 17920.0  0.0   10245.0 275456.0 245131.8  183808.0   27873.0   54744.0 51899.0 7168.0 6607.3      9    0.153   2      0.069    0.221
Timestamp        S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       MC     MU    CCSC   CCSU   YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   
           69.2 13824.0 17408.0 10054.2  0.0   307200.0 35229.6   183808.0   27900.0   54744.0 51915.2 7168.0 6607.3     10    0.165   2      0.069    0.234
           70.2 13824.0 17408.0 10054.2  0.0   307200.0 105302.8  183808.0   27900.0   54744.0 51915.2 7168.0 6607.3     10    0.165   2      0.069    0.234
           71.2 13824.0 17408.0 10054.2  0.0   307200.0 175375.9  183808.0   27900.0   54744.0 51915.2 7168.0 6607.3     10    0.165   2      0.069    0.234
           72.2 13824.0 17408.0 10054.2  0.0   307200.0 245524.3  183808.0   27900.0   54744.0 51915.2 7168.0 6607.3     10    0.165   2      0.069    0.234
           73.2 13312.0 10752.0  0.0   10294.8 297472.0  5755.9   183808.0   27900.0   54744.0 51916.4 7168.0 6607.3     11    0.186   2      0.069    0.254
Timestamp        S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       MC     MU    CCSC   CCSU   YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   
           74.2 13312.0 10752.0  0.0   10294.8 297472.0 74923.0   183808.0   27900.0   54744.0 51916.4 7168.0 6607.3     11    0.186   2      0.069    0.254
           75.2 13312.0 10752.0  0.0   10294.8 297472.0 144067.0  183808.0   27900.0   54744.0 51916.4 7168.0 6607.3     11    0.186   2      0.069    0.254
           76.2 13312.0 10752.0  0.0   10294.8 297472.0 220150.7  183808.0   27900.0   54744.0 51916.4 7168.0 6607.3     11    0.186   2      0.069    0.254
           77.3 13312.0 10752.0  0.0   10294.8 297472.0 294977.6  183808.0   27900.0   54744.0 51916.4 7168.0 6607.3     11    0.186   2      0.069    0.254
           78.3 10240.0 16384.0 10211.3  0.0   287744.0 62041.7   183808.0   27908.0   54744.0 51916.4 7168.0 6607.3     12    0.210   2      0.069    0.278
Timestamp        S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       MC     MU    CCSC   CCSU   YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   
           79.3 10240.0 16384.0 10211.3  0.0   287744.0 135303.3  183808.0   27908.0   54744.0 51916.4 7168.0 6607.3     12    0.210   2      0.069    0.278
           80.3 10240.0 16384.0 10211.3  0.0   287744.0 202901.9  183808.0   27908.0   54744.0 51916.4 7168.0 6607.3     12    0.210   2      0.069    0.278
           81.3 10240.0 16384.0 10211.3  0.0   287744.0 270500.5  183808.0   27908.0   54744.0 51916.4 7168.0 6607.3     12    0.210   2      0.069    0.278
           82.3 12800.0 10240.0  0.0   10213.9 278528.0 49487.8   183808.0   27908.0   54744.0 51917.1 7168.0 6607.3     13    0.233   2      0.069    0.301
           83.3 12800.0 10240.0  0.0   10213.9 278528.0 120919.5  183808.0   27908.0   54744.0 51917.1 7168.0 6607.3     13    0.233   2      0.069    0.301
Timestamp        S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       MC     MU    CCSC   CCSU   YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   
           84.3 12800.0 10240.0  0.0   10213.9 278528.0 186838.9  183808.0   27908.0   54744.0 51917.1 7168.0 6607.3     13    0.233   2      0.069    0.301
           85.3 12800.0 10240.0  0.0   10213.9 278528.0 258251.7  183808.0   27908.0   54744.0 51917.1 7168.0 6607.3     13    0.233   2      0.069    0.301
           86.3 10240.0 15872.0 10022.2  0.0   269824.0 48156.7   183808.0   27916.0   54744.0 51917.1 7168.0 6607.3     14    0.250   2      0.069    0.319
           87.3 10240.0 15872.0 10022.2  0.0   269824.0 117672.6  183808.0   27916.0   54744.0 51917.1 7168.0 6607.3     14    0.250   2      0.069    0.319
           88.3 10240.0 15872.0 10022.2  0.0   269824.0 192535.9  183808.0   27916.0   54744.0 51917.1 7168.0 6607.3     14    0.250   2      0.069    0.319
Timestamp        S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       MC     MU    CCSC   CCSU   YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   
           89.3 10240.0 15872.0 10022.2  0.0   269824.0 267411.0  183808.0   27916.0   54744.0 51917.1 7168.0 6607.3     14    0.250   2      0.069    0.319
           90.3 11776.0 10240.0  0.0   10035.6 261632.0 72846.4   183808.0   27924.0   54744.0 51920.4 7168.0 6607.3     15    0.267   2      0.069    0.335
           91.3 11776.0 10240.0  0.0   10035.6 261632.0 130365.8  183808.0   27924.0   54744.0 51920.4 7168.0 6607.3     15    0.267   2      0.069    0.335
           92.3 11776.0 10240.0  0.0   10035.6 261632.0 130365.8  183808.0   27924.0   54744.0 51920.4 7168.0 6607.3     15    0.267   2      0.069    0.335
           93.3 11776.0 10240.0  0.0   10035.6 261632.0 130365.8  183808.0   27924.0   54744.0 51920.4 7168.0 6607.3     15    0.267   2      0.069    0.335
Timestamp        S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       MC     MU    CCSC   CCSU   YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   
           94.2 11776.0 10240.0  0.0   10035.6 261632.0 130932.7  183808.0   27924.0   54744.0 51920.4 7168.0 6607.3     15    0.267   2      0.069    0.335
           95.2 11776.0 10240.0  0.0   10035.6 261632.0 130932.7  183808.0   27924.0   54744.0 51920.4 7168.0 6607.3     15    0.267   2      0.069    0.335
           96.2 11776.0 10240.0  0.0   10035.6 261632.0 130932.7  183808.0   27924.0   54744.0 51920.4 7168.0 6607.3     15    0.267   2      0.069    0.335
           97.2 11776.0 10240.0  0.0   10035.6 261632.0 130932.7  183808.0   27924.0   54744.0 51920.4 7168.0 6607.3     15    0.267   2      0.069    0.335
           98.2 11776.0 10240.0  0.0   10035.6 261632.0 130932.7  183808.0   27924.0   54744.0 51920.4 7168.0 6607.3     15    0.267   2      0.069    0.335
Timestamp        S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       MC     MU    CCSC   CCSU   YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   
           99.3 11776.0 10240.0  0.0   10035.6 261632.0 130932.7  183808.0   27924.0   54744.0 51920.4 7168.0 6607.3     15    0.267   2      0.069    0.335
          100.3 11776.0 10240.0  0.0   10035.6 261632.0 130932.7  183808.0   27924.0   54744.0 51920.4 7168.0 6607.3     15    0.267   2      0.069    0.335
          101.3 11776.0 10240.0  0.0   10035.6 261632.0 130932.7  183808.0   27924.0   54744.0 51920.4 7168.0 6607.3     15    0.267   2      0.069    0.335
          102.3 11776.0 10240.0  0.0   10035.6 261632.0 130932.7  183808.0   27924.0   54744.0 51920.4 7168.0 6607.3     15    0.267   2      0.069    0.335
          103.3 11776.0 10240.0  0.0   10035.6 261632.0 130932.7  183808.0   27924.0   54744.0 51920.4 7168.0 6607.3     15    0.267   2      0.069    0.335
Timestamp        S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       MC     MU    CCSC   CCSU   YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   
          104.3 11776.0 10240.0  0.0   10035.6 261632.0 130932.7  183808.0   27924.0   54744.0 51920.4 7168.0 6607.3     15    0.267   2      0.069    0.335
          105.3 11776.0 10240.0  0.0   10035.6 261632.0 130932.7  183808.0   27924.0   54744.0 51920.4 7168.0 6607.3     15    0.267   2      0.069    0.335
          106.3 11776.0 10240.0  0.0   10035.6 261632.0 130932.7  183808.0   27924.0   54744.0 51920.4 7168.0 6607.3     15    0.267   2      0.069    0.335
          107.3 11776.0 10240.0  0.0   10035.6 261632.0 130932.7  183808.0   27924.0   54744.0 51920.4 7168.0 6607.3     15    0.267   2      0.069    0.335
          108.3 11776.0 10240.0  0.0   10035.6 261632.0 130932.7  183808.0   27924.0   54744.0 51920.4 7168.0 6607.3     15    0.267   2      0.069    0.335
Timestamp        S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       MC     MU    CCSC   CCSU   YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   
          109.3 11776.0 10240.0  0.0   10035.6 261632.0 130932.7  183808.0   27924.0   54744.0 51920.4 7168.0 6607.3     15    0.267   2      0.069    0.335
          110.3 11776.0 10240.0  0.0   10035.6 261632.0 130932.7  183808.0   27924.0   54744.0 51920.4 7168.0 6607.3     15    0.267   2      0.069    0.335
          111.3 11776.0 10240.0  0.0   10035.6 261632.0 130932.7  183808.0   27924.0   54744.0 51920.4 7168.0 6607.3     15    0.267   2      0.069    0.335
```

what's wrong with my code?

Comment: You can start by paginating you SELECT statement. That way you have to process less rows.

Comment: @AxelRichter it's does't matter here, If I understand SXSSFWorkbook correctly, when specify `new SXSSFWorkbook(1000)`, only 1000 rows should be in memory, while extra rows will be write to tmp file on disk..

Comment: This sample might be worth experimenting with (needs POI 5.2.+) -  https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/poi-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/examples/xssf/streaming/DeferredGeneration.java

Comment: @AxelRichter as your said, 1000 rows memory usage should be less than 10M, but jstat output shows that heap usage increased almost 200M, not on same level.